# How to tell if a remote file path corresponds to one filter

Tags: c#, windows, file, filter, explorer

Currently, I have obtained these paths in a remote folder.

```
/folder 1/subfolder 2/filea.jpg

/folder 1/subfolder 2/fileb.pdf

/folder 1/subfolder 3/filea.jpg
```

And i have settled filters to decide whether I should download a file in the path list, based on the windows file explorer, e.g.

```
/folder ?/subfolder ?/*.jpg

/*/*/abc.*

/*/*/*.*
```

What is the best way to achieve a decision whether download it or not?

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Are you trying to select all .jpg files in a directory?

Comment: No it is just an example, it could be any kind of file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to use a combination of the [`Directory.EnumerateDirectories()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383462(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`Directory.GetFiles()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f(v=vs.110).aspx) methods, both of which take in a `string searchPattern` argument.

Note: To use the `Directory` class, you need to use the `System.IO` namespace at the top of your file:

```
using System.IO;
```

I believe you will have to enumerate each directory separately, since a backslash character is illegal in a file or directory name.

For example, you could have a method that takes a `rootPath` (the topmost directory you're searching under) and returns all "*.jpg" files that reside in a directory named "subfolder ?" (where the `?` is a placeholder for a single character) only if the subfolder is directly under a directory named "folder ?":

```
/// <summary>
/// Searches for files using the pattern "/folder ?/subfolder ?/*.jpg"
/// </summary>
/// <param name="rootPath">The directory in which to begin the search</param>
/// <returns>A list of file paths that meet the criteria</returns>
public static List<string> GetDownloadableFiles(string rootPath)
{
    var files = new List<string>();

    // First find all the directories that match 'folder ?', anywhere under 'rootPath'
    foreach (var directory in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(rootPath, "folder ?", 
        SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    {
        // Now find all directories directly under 'folder ?' named 'subfolder ?'
        foreach (var subDir in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(directory, "subfolder ?"))
        {
            // And add the file path for all '*.jpg' files to our list
            files.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(subDir, "*.jpg"));
        }
    }

    return files;
}
```

In use, you would do something like:

```
List<string> downloadableFiles = GetDownloadableFiles(@"\\server\share");
```

---

With that method completed that addresses your specific example, we can see now how we could make this more generic, so the client can pass in any sort of search string.

If we say that the delimiter character in our search string is a forward slash (`/`), then we can let the user pass in the string and we can split it on that character. This will give us an array of directory search patterns and a file search pattern (the last item).

Once we do that, we can loop over the search patterns, getting directories that match the current pattern and storing them in a temporary list on each iteration, until we get to the last part (which is the file search pattern), where we get the files that match that pattern.

For example:

```
/// <summary>
/// Searches for files using the pattern defined in 'searchPattern'
/// Example search patterns: "/project ?/photoshoot ?/flowers ?/*.jpg"
///                          "/project ?/plans ?/*.pdf"
///                          "/project ?/*.txt"
/// </summary>
/// <param name="rootPath">The directory in which to begin the search</param>
/// <param name="searchPattern">The directory and file search pattern</param>
/// <returns>A list of file paths that meet the criteria</returns>
public static List<string> GetDownloadableFiles(string rootPath, string searchPattern)
{
    if (!Directory.Exists(rootPath)) 
        throw new DirectoryNotFoundException(nameof(rootPath));
    if (searchPattern == null) 
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(searchPattern));

    var files = new List<string>();
    var searchParts = searchPattern.Split(new[] {'/'}, 
        StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    // This will hold the list of directories to search, and 
    // will be updated on each iteration of our loop below. 
    // We start with just one item: the 'rootPath'
    var searchFolders = new List<string> {rootPath};

    for (int i = 0; i < searchParts.Length; i++)
    {
        var subFolders = new List<string>();

        foreach (var searchFolder in searchFolders)
        {
            // If we're at the last item, it's the file pattern, so add files
            if (i == searchParts.Length - 1)
            {
                files.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(searchFolder, searchParts[i]));
            }
            // Otherwise, add the sub directories for this pattern
            else
            {
                subFolders.AddRange(Directory.GetDirectories(searchFolder, 
                    searchParts[i]));
            }
        }

        // Reset our search folders to use the list from the latest pattern
        searchFolders = subFolders;
    }

    return files;
}
```

Example usage:

```
var files = GetDownloadableFiles(@"\\server\share", "/folder ?/subfolder ?/*.jpg");
```

Comment: The thing is that the paths are remote paths, so the system can't check locally for files.

Besides it could be any other type of filter, given by the user, so I need to look for .pdf or .pnd, It depends all on the filter.

Comment: The example I showed uses a remote path. Did this not work for your remote path? Also, you could parameterize the filters on the method to make it more generic. I'll post an example of that.

Comment: Added an example that takes the root path to search and a string that represents the search pattern.